# Adding multiple circles to a JFrame? (Java)

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am trying to draw circles to JFrame with different positions, in this case in a grid-like pattern.

I don't seem to have trouble drawing a single circle with an x,y position, however, when I try to draw multiple circles with different positions the other circles' positions come out obscured.

In the code below, I have two arrays: XPlacements and YPlacements that contain different X and Y positions to form a grid. For each X position there should be circles created at that X position with varying Y positions (vice versa).

When I only make the below code draw one circle, where XPlacements = {10} YPlacements = {100}, it draws a circle that appears to be at some (10,100) from the top left. Similarly when I add multiple X positions but a single Y position nothing seems to be obscured. However, when I add multiple Y positions, every descending row of circles seems to be more and more pushed to the right.
When I run it, it obscures like this: [http://imgur.com/HHjhvPD](https://imgur.com/HHjhvPD)

*I can't seem to make it less obscured by changing the values of the JFrame. All the JFrame circle tutorials I can find only deal with 1 circle, and I don't have any issues when I use 1 circle (or only 1 row of circles)*.

Does anyone know why the code below isn't producing a grid like pattern?

Thanks.

```
public class Circle extends Canvas {
int XPos;
int YPos;
public void SetPosition(int x, int y) {
    this.XPos = x;
    this.YPos = y;
    repaint();
}
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    System.out.println("Filling oval with position ("+XPos+","+YPos+")");
    g.fillOval(XPos, YPos, 15, 15);
}
}

public class MainFile extends JFrame {
static int[] XPlacements = {10,20,30};
static int[] YPlacements = {100,200,300};
static Circle[] Circles = new Circle[1000];
static int Circle_Count = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Grid of circles");
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1)); 
    frame.setSize(800, 800);

    for(int x=0;x<XPlacements.length;x++) {
        for(int y=0;y<YPlacements.length;y++) {
            System.out.println("Creating new circle "+Circle_Count+" with position "+XPlacements[x]+","+YPlacements[y]);
            Circles[Circle_Count] = new Circle();
            Circles[Circle_Count].SetPosition(XPlacements[x],YPlacements[y]);
            frame.add(Circles[Circle_Count]);
            Circle_Count++;
        }
    }
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: Try `new GridLayout(YPlacements.length,XPlacements.length)`

Comment: What's the meaning of using an array Circles[], using a counter etc. in this simple case?  You can use a single component variable:

    <static Circle comp;>
    <comp = new Circle();>
    <comp.SetPosition(XPlacements[x],YPlacements[y]);>
    <frame.add(obj); frame.validate();>

It would only have a meaning if you needed to keep different names of each added component so that you can remove any of them individually ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all this is a Swing application so custom painting should be done by overriding paintComponent() of a JPanel. A Canvas is an AWT component that should not be used in a Swing application.

If you want to draw on a component then the custom painting is always done relative to offset (0, 0). So in your case the code would be:

```
//g.fillOval(XPos, YPos, 15, 15);
g.fillOval(0, 0, 15, 15);
```

Then you need to override the getPreferredSize() method of your class to set the size of the component:

```
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize()
{
    return new Dimension(15, 15);
}
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more informations and working examples.

Now the layout manager has information about the component and can position each component on the panel:

So the code to add the Circles to the frame would be something like:

```
frame.setLayout( new GridLayout(3, 3, 50, 50) );

for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
    frame.add( new Circle() );
}
```

This will create a 3x3 grid with a gap of 50 pixels between each component.